# Android: Keep CPU running and shut screen off (Not dimmed)

Tags: java, android, android-wake-lock

I am trying to turn my device screen off while the device's CPU remains awake. I  have tried a few different things but I am unable to turn the screen completely off programmatically.

I have done some research and saw that using `WakeLock` can dim the screen / leave room for the screen to be turned off while the CPU is still running and that seems to work:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
```

In order to turn the screen off completely, I have tried to change the screen time-out, but that only dims the screen:

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 1);
```

Is there any other way that I can turn the screen off completely while the CPU is still running ?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, except I'm using the NDK.

Comment: Mhmm, I'm sure this is possible some way or another. I will update you if I figure this out before an answer gets posted.